# Dropdown list is not retaining the selected value after submitting the form in Asp.net core Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

The dropdown list is not retaining the selected value after submitting the form. The data got from the search is correct. What should I do to retain the selected dropdown value?
This is the action

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllLeaves(IFormCollection obj ,string currentFilter, 
           string searchLeaveType)
{
 ViewData["CurrentFilterLT"] = obj["searchLeaveType"].ToString();

            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchLeaveType))
            {
                leaves = leaves.Where(l => l.LeaveType == searchLeaveType);
            }
return View(leaves);
}
```

This is the View

```
                             <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Leave Type</label>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <select name="searchLeaveType" id="searchLeaveType" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilterLT"]">
                                     
                                        <option>--Select--</option>
                                        <option value="Annual Leave">Annual Leave</option>
                                        <option value="Casual Leave">Casual Leave</option>
                                        <option value="Sick Leave">Sick Leave</option>
                                        <option value="Maternity Leave">Maternity Leave</option>
                                        <option value="Parental Leave">Parental Leave</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">Search</button>
                          <button type="reset" id="reset" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Did you debug the code and check the values being used? Were they correct? Why are you using `searchLeaveType` in one place and  `obj["searchLeaveType"]` in another? How are they different? Why use both? Where did you declare `leaves`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the drop-down list value, the  attribute selected of the option will not be changed, so it will not show the selected value.

You can change it through javascript.

```
<script>
    $('#searchLeaveType').val('@ViewData["CurrentFilterLT"]')
</script>
```